# CoreData fetch request returns an object with nil properties when changing app state

Tags: swift, core-data

I have some code that helps with managing current Managed Object Context

```
var currentContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        return mainContext
    } else {
        return backgroundContext
    }
}

var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}

lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.parent = mainContext
    
    return context
}()
```

Fetch function

```
public func entities(_ fetchOptions: FetchOptions) -> [T] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: T.entityName)
    
    switch fetchOptions {
    case let .filtered(predicate):
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    case let .sorted(sortDescriptors):
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    case let .filteredAndSorted(predicate, sortDescriptors):
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    case .all:
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []
    }
    
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    
    let context = CoreDataContextProvider.provider.currentContext
    
    return (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)) ?? []
}
```

Let's say I have a request that gets some data from the server and writes it to the CoreData. When i use the app in the foreground, everything works well, but when i enter the background, for example, switch into another app, and then go back, fetch request from current context for a particular entity returns something like

```
SomeEntity {
   var property1 = 0;
   var property2 = nil;
   var property3 = nil;
   ... etc
}
```

Data is correct in the background context, and I get this behaviour exactly after switching back to the main one.

I've tried saving current context on `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`, so that changes got pushed anyway, but it seems to do no favour.

Also, I've tried to merge main and background context on `NSManagedObject.didSaveObjectsNotification`, and got same results, but I don't rule out that I did something wrong here.

When I use main context only, everything seems to be working fine, but I get serious UI freezes once in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to let main context do this merging stuff for me, there is actually a method that creates new background context without it being the pain in the ass:

```swift
persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
```

Now everything works fine